# Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial with a math function output

Tags: numpy, scipy, numbers, symbolic-math

So i have been coding a numerical Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial solver. But i cant get a actual mathematical function output. Found a webpage https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial where i can just put in the numbers and get a function. How do they do it?

Comment: Could you provide the code you've written so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at Sympy (https://sympy.org), there is probably a symbolic Lagrange interpolation function, something like, you put in the support points and it returns a polynomial which interpolates those points. I'm more familiar with Maxima, you can look at the `lagrange` function to see how it would go. Take a look at the example in: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_261.html#index-lagrange